# Permission denied when creating temporary files

Tags: permissions

I am currently attempting to install pccloud on ubuntu 20.04, via the following instructions:

https://github.com/pcloudcom/console-client

It goes fine until I get to the second from the bottom line, when I get this error message:

```
ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

Comment: `ldconfig` needs to be run as root: `sudo ldconfig`

Answer (score 3):

`Permission denied` shows that the command can't be run by a normal user, but only as a root.
Run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```